# using Select() method to load the 3rd degree entity from the database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Let's assume that I have the following relationship among three entities: **A->B->C**

Each Bs is associated with ONLY ONE C and ONE A. Each A can have many Bs and similarly each C can be associated with many Bs.

I have the following Linq to load the Cs when I fetch the A records from the database:

```
 db.A_dbSet.Include(a => a.Bs.Select(b => b.C).ToList();
```

This works fine. However, I am not sure how Select() functions here. Does it function similar to Include() but we have to use Select() instead of Include() since Bs navigation property of A is List collection?

Can I read the linq expression above like this: Load all As, bring all related Bs, while bringing related Bs do not forget the associated Cs of each B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I read the linq expression above like this: Load all As, bring all related Bs, while bringing related Bs do not forget the associated Cs of each B.

I guess you can, according to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671236(v=vs.103).aspx)

> The path expression must be composed of simple property access expressions together with calls to **Select** in order to compose additional includes after including a collection property. Examples of possible include paths are:
>
> - *To include a single reference:* query.Include(e => e.Level1Reference).
> - *To include a single collection:* query.Include(e => e.Level1Collection).
> - *To include a reference and then a reference one level down:* query.Include(e => e.Level1Reference.Level2Reference).
> - *To include a reference and then a collection one level down:* query.Include(e => e.Level1Reference.Level2Collection).
> - *To include a collection and then a reference one level down:* query.Include(e => e.Level1Collection.Select(l1 => l1.Level2Reference)).
> - *To include a collection and then a collection one level down:* query.Include(e => e.Level1Collection.Select(l1 => l1.Level2Collection)).
> - *To include a collection and then a reference one level down:* query.Include(e => e.Level1Collection.Select(l1 => l1.Level2Reference)).
> - *To include a collection and then a collection one level down:* query.Include(e => e.Level1Collection.Select(l1 => l1.Level2Collection)).
> - *To include a collection, a reference, and a reference two levels down:* query.Include(e => e.Level1Collection.Select(l1 => l1.Level2Reference.Level3Reference)).
> - *To include a collection, a collection, and a reference two levels down:* query.Include(e => e.Level1Collection.Select(l1 => l1.Level2Collection.Select(l2 => l2.Level3Reference))).

By my understanding `Select` is just a recognizable expression placeholder, similar to canonical functions, but specific to `Include`.

Comment: that is the documentation I was looking for, thanks!